# I have this problem on how to repeat the table inside the ng-repeat based on the field value

Tags: angularjs

I have this problem on how to repeat the table inside the ng-repeat based on the field[rm_count_rack] value

See below the sample and possible outcome.

this is my database.

[image]

This is the display of `ng-repeat="i in room"`

[image]

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" ng-repeat="i in room" > 
    <br>
    <table class="column"> **<!-- need to repeat this table based on the
                                  value of i.rm_count_rack** -->
        <th colspan="{{i.rm_subbin}}" class="text-center">RACK A</th>
        <tbody >
          <tr>
            <td ><a style="width: 100%" href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-info"><span>1A62</span></a></td>
            <td><a style="width: 100%" href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-success"><span>1A62</span></a></td>
            <td><a style="width: 100%" href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-danger"><span>1A62</span></a></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

This should be the output:

[image]

Comment: Could you please share the data in ** room **

Comment: rm_id rm_no rm_count_rack
1 1 2
2 2 2
3 3 2

Comment: I was expecting a JSON :) :)

Comment: $statement=$db->prepare("SELECT rm_count_rack FROM room_details");
$statement->execute();
$results=$statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


$myData = array('results' => $results);

echo $json =json_encode($myData);

Comment: tthen my scope: httpget     $http.get('model/racklayout.php')
            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.room = response.data.results;
            });

Answer (score 0):

Since `ng-repeat` only accepts a collection as a parameter. You could try:

```
<table class="column" ng-repeat="x in [].constructor(i.rm_count_rack) track by $index">
```

Or

```
<table class="column" ng-repeat="x in getNumber(i.rm_count_rack)">
```

And inside your controller

```
$scope.getNumber = function(num) {
    return new Array(num);   
}
```

Comment: I've already tried this but my desire output will not show, it will only show 3 rows. i have this database with 3 rows its row has  2 rm_count_rack. so this should be the output in one row there should be 2 racks.